# Is it a good idea to write the whole code in the ViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I've developed an App with Swift. Now I want to know if it's a good idea to write whole code in the ViewController or is it better to create more classes?
So can you recommend writing everything in the ViewController from your own experience?
The App I created is a camera and I think that it's inconvinient to have more classes, isn't it?

Comment: [SOLID (object-oriented design)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: its not about the Swift, modular programming is the most preferable way which later makes easy to optimize code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just follow the MVC (Model View Controller) pattern since that's how UIKit is written.

According to the MVC design pattern, the controller contains UI logic. It responds to changes in the model and the views' events (e.g. tapping). This means that you should not draw your custom views in the controller. Do that in a separate view class. Also, create model classes where neccesary. For example, a `Filter` class that represents a filter that you can add to the camera.

Remember that the model should be UI independent!

Answer (score 1):

There are some good design pattern for your project like MVC, MVVM and other also. Can divide your code in the other part like Singleton class and Model class help you manage your code better way separate your applications business logic and any other reusable code or extensions.

Here i am providing you the good one [VIPER architecture.](https://github.com/mutualmobile/VIPER-SWIFT)

Answer (score 0):

Not depends on iOS and ViewController, in any case write all in one class is bad practice. Follow more about [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles and other software design rules and suggestions.